# If rows contain some key words then hide the rows: with rumtime error type 13

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a question about my code to hide rows, when the rows contain some certain key words, as the worksheet is activated.
By testing, my code runs well and I didn't have any errors.

However, it seems that my code is rather vulnerable. Some of the colleagues have often the error reports, if they insert rows or delete rows, which causes the formula reference errors, because I use the “if” formula to produce the “key words”.

What I don’t understand is why this can cause error type 13: type mismatch… and the row "If InStr(1, LCase(MainString), LCase(SubString)) <> 0 Then..." is marked. I read the explanation of Microsoft, but still not understand what type is mismatched here and what I can do to prevent this error.

Thanks a lot for your time and your suggestion in advance!

Screenshots of my rows in the table and error reporting:

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim MainString As String
Dim SubString As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call unhidden

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A150").End(xlUp).Row
SubString = "risiko benannt"


For i = 9 To lastrow
MainString = Range("B" & i)
        If Cells(i, 7).Value > 3 Then
            Cells(i, 18).Value = "Ja"
        End If

        If InStr(1, LCase(MainString), LCase(SubString)) <> 0 Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'll have a Rumtime error type 13 barkeep!

Comment: You need to Set a range object, not assign it. And **no**, I'm not going to retype your code from an image.

Comment: Hello Jeepad, thanks for the reply. The code is below the error screenshot. Sorry my mistake, I took the wrong screenshot. I have changed it. Can you be a little specific? I think the LCase only take string not a range object, or am I wrong about it?

Comment: ? I don't understand it. 'cause my code is below. The screenshot is only to show where the debug highlighted it.

Comment: Thanks Jeepad for your linkings. I understand now!